# Tortoise SVN not working after Windows XP reinstall

Tags: windows, svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn

Before reinstalling, I had Windows XP on C: and lots of SVN checkouts on D:.

Then I formatted C: and re-installed XP on it. Then installed SVN using **Setup-Subversion-1.6.6.msi**, and installed Tortoise using **TortoiseSVN-1.7.7.22907-win32-svn-1.7.5.msi**. (maybe I should have just installed the Tortoise one by itself).

Now when I take a look at my SVN checkouts, Tortoise doesn't seem to recognise what they are. It's treating them as if they were normal directories.

[image: Tortoise context menu]

You can see that this directory has a .svn folder in it, bot Tortoise isn't showing the icon overlays, or the correct context menu.

Is there something I need to do to wake up the Tortoise?

Comment: You have installed a newer version of tortoise (> 1.7) which has a different format. You have to "Upgrade your working copy" as shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

SVN 1.6 and 1.7 working copy formats are incompatible. Install 1.6 Tortoise or convert your working copy to 1.7

Comment: Is this likely to mess up any local modifications I have ?

Comment: I did not try upgrading with local modifications myself, but [according to the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html) it preserves them.

Comment: By the way, it's fairly obvious, but just in case: your command-line client should be of the same version as Tortoise (both 1.6 or both 1.7).

Answer (score 1):

Have a very close look at the screenshot you've posted.
Can you see the entry "`SVN Upgrade working copy`" in the context menu, right above the "`TortoiseSVN`" submenu?
That's TortoiseSVN telling you that your working copy has an old format and you need to upgrade it to the new format.